# I'm trying to prove that $\iint_U dxdy=\iint_V J_{u,v}(x(u,v),y(u,v))\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$

Tags: integration, manifolds

First on $\mathbb R^2$, the space of the 2-form has dimension 1 and thus $$\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\alpha \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v.$$
Let find $a$. I denote $\partial _u$ for $\frac{\partial }{\partial u}$ and $x_u$ for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$.

We have that $\mathrm{d}x=a\mathrm{d}u+b\mathrm{d}y$ and thus $x_u=\mathrm{d}x(\partial u)=a$ and $x_v=\mathrm{d}x(\partial _v)=b$. Therefore $$\mathrm{d}x=x_u\mathrm{d}u+x_v\mathrm{d}v$$
and $$\mathrm{d}y=y_u\mathrm{d}u+y_v\mathrm{d}v.$$

Now $$\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y=(x_u\mathrm{d}u+x_v\mathrm{d}v)\wedge (y_v\mathrm{d}u+y_v\mathrm{d}v)=\\=(x_uy_v-x_vy_y)\mathrm{d}u\wedge \mathrm{d}v=\det J_{u,v}(x(u,v),y(u,v))\mathrm{d}u\wedge \mathrm{d}v.$$

**Q1)** Could someone explain way my proof is not rigorous ? Because I used exactly definition and theorem I have in my course of differentiable manifold, but my teacher said that what I did is not formal.

**Q2)** Supposed I proved that $$\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y=\det J_{u,v}(x,y)\mathrm{d}u\wedge \mathrm{d}v$$

can I conclude directly that $$\iint_U \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\iint_V |\det J_{u,v}(x,y)|\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v \ \ ?$$ 
(if of course I have the right domain $U$ and $V$).

**Q3)** In fact, before I had to write $\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y$ and $\mathrm{d}u\wedge \mathrm{d}v$ that disappeared in the integral. I don't really why we don't write it in the integral. May be $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=|\det J_{u,v}(x,y)|\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$ rather than $\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y=|\det J_{u,v}(x,y)|\mathrm{d}u\wedge \mathrm{d}v$ ? But if so, I know that $$\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=-\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}v$$
but $$\iint \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\iint \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v,$$
so since in the integral it commute, it should have an other reason.

Comment: In things like $f(z)\,dz$ it is standard to put a small space before $dz$ and in things like $a\,dx\,dy$ one has small spaces before both $dx$ and $dy.$ I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Also, in $\displaystyle \iint_V | \det J_{u,v}(x,y)|\,du\,dv,$ notice the odd space before $\det.$ I changed it to $\displaystyle \iint_V \left| \det J_{u,v}(x,y)\right|\,du\,dv,$ coded as \iint_V \left| \det J_{u,v}(x,y)\right|\,du\,dv, using \left and \right. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: thank you.